# Setup for the classical derivation of the magnon dispersion relation

Tags: magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment, ferromagnetism

Suppose in the simplest case of a 1D (line) ferromagnetic crystal in which there are $N$ spins each of magnitude $S$, all of which (spins) are parallel to the external magnetic field.

The Heisenberg interaction (from the Heisenberg model) is described by

$U = -2J\sum_{p=1}^{N} \vec{S_{p}}.\vec{S_{p+1}}$

This interaction equation looks rather similar to the expression given for the starting point of the classical derivation of the magnon dispersion relation, again assuming all spins are parallel to the external magnetic field, given by

$-2J\vec{S_{p}}.(\vec{S_{p-1}}+\vec{S_{p+1}})$

From this equation, it is clear that there is an atom at lattice site $p$ that sits between lattice site $(p-1)$ and $(p+1)$.

What is the physics of the situation such that there is the term $(\vec{S_{p-1}}+\vec{S_{p+1}})$?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which specific derivation you're referring to as "**the** classical derivation of the magnon dispersion", but regardless of whether you have a quantum or classical spin system, these two forms are (up to a factor of $2$) just different ways of writing the sum. Start with
$$
\sum_i \vec{S}_i \cdot \vec{S}_{i+1} = \frac{1}{2} \sum_i \left[ \vec{S}_i  \cdot \vec{S}_{i+1} + \vec{S}_i  \cdot \vec{S}_{i+1} \right].
$$
Assume periodic boundary conditions for simplicity and relabel $i\rightarrow i-1$ in one of the sums to get

$$ \sum_i \vec{S}_i \cdot \vec{S}_{i+1} = \frac{1}{2} \sum_i \left[ \vec{S}_i  \cdot \vec{S}_{i+1} + \vec{S}_{i-1}  \cdot \vec{S}_{i} \right] = \frac{1}{2} \sum_i \vec{S}_i  \cdot \left( \vec{S}_{i-1} + \vec{S}_{i+1}\right).
$$
In other words, the term $\vec{S}_i \cdot \left( \vec{S}_{i-1} + \vec{S}_{i+1}\right)$ just expresses explicitly that each site $i$ interacts with both of its nearest neighbors.